# uniform most powerful test for degenerate likelihood ratio

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

How to compute the distribution like $f(x:\theta)=\begin{cases}
\exp{(-(x-\theta))}& {x>\theta}\\
0& \text{others}
\end{cases}$ 
or
the distribution is like 
$f(x:\theta)=\begin{cases}
\theta x^{-2}& {x>\theta}\\
0& \text{others}
\end{cases}$

When I get the likelihood ratio, it is degenerate and not related to sample X.
I try to solve it like the uniform cases, however, in uniform cases, I can make a transpose so that the parameter $\theta_1$ and $\theta_0$, so that there are no $\theta$ in final expression, but it failed when I deal with these two cases.

Comment: What hypotheses are you testing?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forget to put it. It is the simple hypotheses that $H_0=\theta_0$,$H_1:\theta=\theta_1$,$\theta_1>\theta_0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see none principle differences with $U(0,\theta)$ here.

Consider shifted exponential case.

$$
f(x:\theta)=\begin{cases} \exp{(\theta-x)},& {x>\theta}\cr 0,& x \leq \theta\end{cases}$$
Likelihood function is equal to
$$
f(X_1,\ldots,X_n:\theta)=\begin{cases} \exp{(n\theta-n\overline X)},& {X_{(1)}>\theta}\cr 0,& {X_{(1)}\leq\theta}\end{cases}$$
For $\theta_1>\theta_0$ the likelihood ratio is the following:
$$
\dfrac{f(X_1,\ldots,X_n:\theta_1)}{f(X_1,\ldots,X_n:\theta_0)}=
\begin{cases} \exp{(n\theta_1-n\theta_0)},& {X_{(1)}>\theta_1}\cr 0,& {\theta_0<X_{(1)}\leq\theta_1}\end{cases}$$

We can construct the MPT $\phi$ with probability of type-I error (size of test)
$$\alpha=P_{\theta_0}(\phi=1)\leq P_{\theta_0}\bigl(\,f(X_1,\ldots,X_n:\theta_1)>0\bigr)=P_{\theta_0}(X_{(1)}>\theta_1)=$$
$$=\left(P_{\theta_0}(X_1>\theta_1)\right)^n=\exp(n(\theta_0-\theta_1))\to 0\text{ as } n\to\infty.$$

It means that we should accept $H_0$ when $\theta_0<X_{(1)}\leq\theta_1$ and possibly somewhere else.

This bound appears since for any $\alpha>\exp(n(\theta_0-\theta_1))$ there exists a test with smaller size but with power $1$. Indeed, the MPT with size $\alpha=\exp(n(\theta_0-\theta_1))$ looks as follows:
$$
\phi(X_{(1)})=\begin{cases}1,& X_{(1)}>\theta_1\cr 0, & \theta_0<X_{(1)}\leq\theta_1\end{cases}$$
and the power of this test is alredy $1$:
$$\beta=P_{\theta_1}(\phi=1)=P_{\theta_1}(X_{(1)}>\theta_1)=1.$$

Next, there are two equivalent ways to construct the MPT with $\alpha<\exp(n(\theta_0-\theta_1))$.

**1st way** randomized test:
$$
\phi(X_{(1)})=\begin{cases}p,& X_{(1)}>\theta_1\cr 0, & \theta_0<X_{(1)}\leq\theta_1\end{cases}$$
where $p$ returns the probability to reject $H_0$ in additional coin tossing, and the value of $p$ is defined in such a way that size of test equals $\alpha$. Namely,
$$
\alpha=pP_{\theta_0}(X_{(1)}>\theta_1) = p\exp(n(\theta_0-\theta_1)).
$$
So, $p=\alpha \exp(n(\theta_1-\theta_0))\leq 1$. Remind that $n$ is a fixed number.
The power of this test is equal to 
$$\beta=pP_{\theta_1}(X_{(1)}>\theta_1)=p=\alpha \exp(n(\theta_1-\theta_0)).
$$

**2nd way** (The Karlin–Rubin theorem)
$$
\phi(X_{(1)})=\begin{cases}1,& X_{(1)}>\theta_1+c\cr 0, & \theta_0<X_{(1)}\leq\theta_1+c\end{cases}$$
for some $c>0$. Find $c$:
$$
\alpha=P_{\theta_0}(X_{(1)}>\theta_1+c) = \exp(n(\theta_0-\theta_1-c))=\exp(-nc)\exp(n(\theta_0-\theta_1)).
$$
We obtain $\exp(-nc)=\alpha \exp(n(\theta_1-\theta_0))=p$, where $p$ is the randomizing probability from the "first way".

Calculate the power
$$ 
\beta=P_{\theta_1}(X_{(1)}>\theta_1+c)=\exp(-nc)=\alpha \exp(n(\theta_1-\theta_0))
$$
The powers of tests obtained by both ways are the same. Both tests are MPT.

The second case with Pareto-type distribution can be solved similar way.